# In Elasticsearch, the difference between Array Type and Nested type?

Tags: elasticsearch

I don't know what is the difference between Array Type and Nested type. 
Which one is faster in search than other ?
Thanks;

Comment: elasticsearch does documentation well. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html

Comment: This blog should make things clearer for you: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/

Comment: Thanks MITjanitor and javanna. The problem is more clear now